# Como alterar a propriedade name no @Html.EditorFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho a seguinte classe:

```
public class ModelHome
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Nome")]
        public string Nome { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Messagem")]
        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string Mensagem { get; set; }

    }
```

Meu `Index` tem um `@Html.EditorFor` assim:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nome, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-lg required", @name = "name", @id = "name", @placeholder = "Name", @type = "text" } })
```

A anotação de `Display` na classe eu coloquei para o `Labelfor` já funcionar baseada nela. Mas esse `EditorFor` monta o seguinte HTML:

```
<input class="form-control input-lg required text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo Nome é obrigatório." id="name" name="Nome" placeholder="Name" type="text" value="">
```

A propriedade `name` vem SEMPRE *Nome*, como eu faço para ela vir *name* como está no `@Html.EditorFor` ?

Minhas observações:

- O imput pega a classe, logo o @classe está funcionando.
- Eu já tentei passar os valores em outros parâmetros do construtor,
  não consegui.
- Tentei colocar `@name="name"` ou `name="name"` (sem o @), tb não
  consegui.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A propriedade `name` vem SEMPRE *Nome*, como eu faço para ela vir *name* como está no `@Html.EditorFor`?

`name` e `id` não são alteráveis no `@Html.EditorFor`. Você vai precisar alterar para `@Html.TextBoxFor`:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Nome, new { @class = "form-control input-lg required", Name = "name", @id = "name", @placeholder = "Name" })
```

Comment: O código é isso aí mesmo que você colocou? Não estou conseguindo fazer aparecer name não...

Comment: Perdão, errei a grafia. Veja agora.

Answer (score 0):

tente usar 
Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.Email, new {@name = "nome desejado" })